# Setting content editable caret position from current mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a content editable div that has pre-existing text. This element is by default set to false (not editable), and on double click I am changing the content editable attribute to true and then focusing on the div element.

This is currently selecting all the pre-existing text inside the content editable div, but I would prefer for the caret to be inserted at the closest text DOM node from the mouse cursor position when the double click event fired.

Needing only to support webkit, and having jQuery as a tool if needed, what is the most straight forward way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: @putvande, I don't like being rude but what is the point of your question? Of course I have tried writing my own implementation, and I have not been able to find a proper solution, so I am asking someone more knowledgable about text ranges to help. Lets keep the discourse productive please.

Comment: putvande asked a valid question, you just interpreted it as a yes or no question. Can you please provide some examples of what you have tried already, to help us help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to support chrome you can use [document.caretRangeFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/caretRangeFromPoint)